# BeagleBone Black sending data to a web server using BoneScript

Tags: ajax, web, server, beagleboneblack

How do I send data (via ajax post or get) from BeagleBone Black to a web server using BoneScript?

As I understand, `XMLHttpRequest` does not exist. Is there another approach?

Comment: Just a little syntax polish

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: In fact, I see this operation is not related to beaglebone. It relates to nodejs. So, the key is **require('http')** by node.

```
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://www.example.com', function(response) {
    var response_data = '';

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        response_data += chunk;
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log(response_data);
    })
    .on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
    });
});
```

OR if you want to do that simpler, you can use **[Requistify](http://ranm8.github.io/requestify/)**

```
npm install requestify
```

After installed you can use it like:

```
var requestify = require('requestify');

// GET Example
requestify.get('http://example.com').then(function(response) {
    // Get the response body (JSON parsed - JSON response or jQuery object in case of XML response)
    response.getBody();

    // Get the response raw body
    response.body;
});

// POST example
requestify.post('http://example.com', {
    hello: 'world'
})
.then(function(response) {
    // Get the response body
    response.getBody();
});
```